# What NVME generation does the 9th Generation X1 Carbon support?

Tags: thinkpad, nvme, specifications

[Following in the footsteps of this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/670057/how-can-i-find-out-what-gen-of-nvme-my-machine-supports), if it's not possible to get this data with Linux then where would one find the specs for

> ThinkPad X1 Carbon G9, Intel Core i7-1165G7 (2.80GHz, 12MB)

regarding the NVME support on the hard drive? Should I purchase an NVME gen 3 or NVME gen 4 hard drive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It supports Gen 4 NVME,

### Storage

- Storage Support: One drive, up to 2TB M.2 2280 SSD
- Storage Slot One M.2 2280 PCIe® Gen 4x4 slot, supports M.2 2280 SSD
- Storage Type: Disk Type Interface Security

  - M.2 2280 SSD PCIe NVMe®, PCIe 4.0 x4 Performance Opal2
  - M.2 2280 SSD PCIe NVMe, PCIe x4 Opal2

Source: https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/ThinkPad/ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_Gen_9/ThinkPad_X1_Carbon_Gen_9_Spec.pdf